# datagrid control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have one datagrid in my webform. I want to increase columns in the datagrid based on the data values comes from data values with help of scroll bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the rows in div and add "style=overflow:auto" in the div style Above code will add scroll bars in the grid

Answer (score 0):

Place the Gridview inside the Panel and Assign Panel property ScrollBars="Horizontal"